# Mariadb at synology refusing connection

Tags: python, django, connection, mariadb, synology

I'm trying to connect from my django project to mariadb hosted on my synology nas.
When I try to make migrations, the shell returns that connection was refused all time.

I added a file my.cnf with this: [synology instructions for custom settings](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Service_Application/Can_MariaDB_settings_be_customized_on_Synology_NAS)

```
[mysqld]
skip-networking=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Also created a user with different hosts, including: %, ip of web server, localhost, nas network name,...

Also checked NAS firewall. I created a rule to allow all connections from web server ip. If I disable it a get a time out error, so it seems to work.

My project settings are these:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "db_name,
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pwd',
        'HOST': 'nas ip',
        'DATABASE_PORT':'3307',
    }
}
```

Any clues? I'm lost...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, i didn't get it working :(

Answer (score 1):

Looking the main config file for MariaDB10 which is:
/usr/local/mariadb10/etc/mysql/my.cnf
Which is a symlink to:
-> /volume1/@appstore/MariaDB10/usr/local/mariadb10/etc/mysql/my.cnf

It shows us (truncated):

```
[mariadb]
plugin_load_add = synology_password_check
!include /var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/my.cnf
!include /var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/my_port.cnf
!include /var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/synology.cnf
```

So when you edit '/var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/my.cnf' two more includes are done after yours, with the contents of synology.cnf:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE !!!
# You can change the port on user interface of MariaDB10.
# Please add other custom configuration to /var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
skip_networking=1
```

Thats why it doesnt work. The 'skip_networking=1' comes after yours, superseding your configuration.

My guess to make it work, probably change this file instead.
I really is says dont edit, but '/usr/local/mariadb10/etc/mysql/my.cnf' also says not to edit, so your not left with any choice.

I suspect that if MariaDB ever updates this file will be overwritten, so be careful and remember that if one morning its not working again, that's the reason why.